# CTE and last known date processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**Input**
@StartDate = '01/25/2010'
@EndDate = '02/06/2010'

I have 2 CTEs in a stored procedure as follows:

```
with CTE_A as
(
   [gives output A..Shown below]
),
with CTE_B as
(
  Here,
  I want to check if @StartDate is NOT in output A then replace it with the last known date. In this case, since @startdate is less than any date in output A hence @StartDate will become 02/01/2010.

  Also to check if @EndDate is NOT in output A then replace it with the last known date. In this case, since @enddate is 02/06/2010 hence it will be replace with 02/05/2010.

  // Here there is a query using @startDate and @EndDate.

)
```

**output A**

```
Name   Date   
A      02/01/2010  
B      02/01/2010  
C      02/05/2010  
D      02/10/2010
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  I like solving word problems as much as the next guy, but I'd rather see where those dates come from, and which ones were replaced and which ones were output naturally.

Comment: the dates are input to a stored procedure. i just want to set the input variables to correct dates if they are not in the output A table. hope that explains.

Comment: Nope, still a word problem to me, I guess I'll bow out and let others who can follow provide answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a 2nd CTE (untested)

```
...
SELECT
    StartDate, EndDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            A.Date AS StartDate
        FROM
            CTEA A
        WHERE
            A.[Date] >= @StartDate
        ORDER BY
            A.Date
    ) Bmin
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            A.Date AS EndDate
        FROM
            CTEA A
        WHERE
            A.[Date] <= @EndDate
        ORDER BY
            A.Date DESC
    ) Bmax
```

You could use MAX/MIN too